# jquery validate .resetForm() not clearing form, validation messages firing on manual reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Ive got several buttons, passing different params to the same function.  That function will eventually do lots of client side processing but first it needs to validate.  Validation is working fine, but upon success, I need to reset the form.  In my fiddle below, you can see that the .resetForm() call does nothing, and if I manually clear the field, it throws validation errors like I was trying to submit.

see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uT6pw/10/

html:

```
    <form id="frm" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
         <input type="text" id="FName" class="required">
         <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>    
         <button id="btn1" onclick="addContact('1')">1</button>
         <button id="btn2" onclick="addContact('2')">2</button>
         <button id="btn3" onclick="addContact('3')">3</button>
    </form>
```

javascript:

```
function addContact(num){
    var v = $("#frm").validate()
    if (v.form())
    {
        v.resetForm();
        //$("#frm").validate().resetForm()
        $("#FName").val('');
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not heard about resetForm, try this:

```
form.reset();
```

**Update**: You have button tags that post form, this is the reason form gets validated when you click them. Instead change `<button>` to `<input type="button"/>`

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uT6pw/13/)

Comment: I`m attempting to use the Validate plugin for JQuery, resetForm() is a method in that plugin.

Comment: I also tried $("#frm")[0].reset(); and while it clears the field, it throws the validation message same as if I set the .val().

Comment: Thanks Karax, I ended up completely changing the form to take advantage of the submithandler functionality in the validate plugin.  Your fix would have been easier had it come in time.  Thanks!

Comment: @Justin it's sad that i was late :(